# Guardar musica para usar en HTML

Tags: html5, angular6, audio

Estoy intentando crear una aplicacion, llamese una botonera, y necesito guardar las canciones. Los temas estan en SoundCloud, pero no puedo utilizarlos desde ahi a mi HTML.

Hay algun lugar donde pueda subir o alguna manera que pueda hacer para tener mis canciones y que pueda tener en mi HTML una URL para poder reproducir esas canciones?

O cual seria la manera mas real de hacer algo asi? Tener canciones para que las reproduzca la App.

Comment: Claro, pero no tengo dos o tres audios. Manejo mas de veinte y no puedo tener todos esos porque la aplicacion va a pesar mucho. Por eso pregunto porque no sabia si hay otra manera de poder utilizar los audios sin tener que tenerlo localmente en la aplicacion.

Comment: si son links no estan en tu apliacion asi puedes tener 10000...., pero que llevas hasta el momento y cual es la duda en cuanto a programacion?

Comment: Es decir, obtener los link y reproducir esas canciones en tu sitio?